# how to modify program interrupt in assembly?

Tags: assembly, emu8086, interruptions

I am a little novice in assembler programming but I have a little homework that requires a lot of reflection, I have to modify the interrupt subroutine, for example when I call int21h, I want to display a message HELLO WORD,or when I want to do a division by 0,I want to display the number 5 for example, so I know the all segrment of vector interrupt is CS:0000 and offset is 0084(for int21h) 
and Is it requested to when I want call int21, I want my microprocessor execute another program that can be found in [0700:1200] , so I need to change the content 0000:0084 (the adress of int 21 ); I tried A idea is 
mov [0000],0700
mov [0084],1200

but unfortunately doesn't work 
there is my example

```
org 100 
mov dx,000
push ds
mov ds,dx
lea bx,qwert  
mov [0084h],1500h
int 21h hlt 
org 1200
jmp qwert
pa equ 20h
pb equ 22h`
pc equ 24h
regcontrol equ 26h
tab db 3fh,06h,5bh,4FH,66H,6Dh,7dh,07h,7fh,6fh
com equ 90h
qwert:        
 mov ax,com
out regcontrol,ax 
debut:
mov al,0FFH
OUT pc,al
  call tempo
  mov al,00h
  out pc,al
  call tempo
  jmp debut 
ret   

 proc tempo
    mov cx,7fffh
   ici:nop
   nop
   nop
   nop
   nop
   nop
     loop ici 
       ret
     endp
```

so , what I want is when to I execute int21h , i want to this interruption go directly to execute the program qwerty , the program qwerty is founded in 0700:0112 ( I use emu 8086) , but int 21h goes directly to f400:1500.

I hope you understand me and sorry for my bad english

Comment: You also need to set the segment part of the far pointer of the interrupt vector 21h: `mov ax, cs / mov WORD PTR [21h*4+2], ax`. Also, 1500h and 1200 are two very different numbers. P.S. The code is unreadable, has meaningless instructions and `int 21h hlt` which should not even assemble.

Comment: thanks for your reply, sorry for the code and yes is 1200 not 1500 just a mistake but nothing is changed , qwert is a program flicking a led ,so I want when i call int 21h, the interrupt program of int21h execute qwert program + can you explain me How these instructions can help me ?

Comment: Every interrupt vector has 4 bytes (segment:offset). You write only the offset part by `mov [0084h],1500h` (and why not `mov [0084h],bx`, if you already did `lea bx,qwert`? Do you understand what those instructions does, or do you just copy/paste them from some examples and try to change thing here and there until it works?) If you understand Margaret's comment, edit your code to show latest version with how you applied that solution (it's full solution, so it's not clear why you are failing at using it, show the updated code and/or ask what you don't understand, be precise please).

Answer (score 2):

Now I read your question fully... Some things are maybe worth answer:

> so I know the all segrment of vector interrupt is CS:0000 and offset is 0084(for int21h)

That's mixing up several things. `cs` is register, together with `ip` it stores address (`cs:ip`) of instruction to be executed next. While you are in your own code at the beginning, `cs = 0700h`, until you jump elsewhere through `int 21h`.

The interrupt vector table (contains addresses of interrupt handling routines) is in memory starting at `0000:0000` address.

Every entry in the table consist of four bytes, so then offset for `21h` is `21h*4 = 84h` (not 84, but 84h == 132).

Those four bytes of single entry are `segment:offset` address of routine, the offset part is stored as first word, segment part is the second word (at `0:86h`). Your original code does set only offset part, but not segment, that's why it jumps to `F400h:1500h`, you didn't change that old `F400h` of original DOS handler.

> ... so I need to change the content 0000:0084 (the adress of int 21 );

Yes (although you want to modify 21h, so the address is 84h, but your sentence is true even for decimal values, if you would want to change `int 15h`, then address `0000:0084` would be correct).

> I tried A idea is mov [0000],0700 mov [0084],1200

No. `mov [0000],0700` does modify memory at `ds:0000`. Re-read some explanation what segment:offset in x86 16b real mode means (physical address = segment*16 + offset).

So when `int 21h` vector is at (all numbers will be hexa from here) `0000:0084`, that means it is at physical memory address `0000 * 10 + 0084 = 00084`. At address `0000:0000` is vector for `int 0`.

If you see `0000:0084`, that is not two offsets (to modify [0000] and [0084]), but that's single memory address pointing to the first byte of the value. And to store 32 bit `segment:offset` value means to write 16b offset part into bytes at +0 and +1, and 16b segment value to +2 and +3 bytes.

So if the old `int 21h` handler was for example `F400:DEAD`, then the memory at address `0000:0084` contain four bytes: `AD DE 00 F4`. Use memory view in debugger to see the interrupt table and it's initial content. Your original code from question does modify that to `00 15 00 F4`, and then `int 21h` does jump to that address (`F400:1500`).

Comment: the correct address for int 21 is `DEAD:BABE`, not of `F400:DEAD` ;-)